# Array.push() with Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is there any reason why I canot .push() objects into an Array? Simplified example below.

```
let myArray = [{x:1},{x:2}];

let myObj = {x:1};

let x = myArray.push(myObj);

console.log(x)
```

// I'am expecting [{x:1},{x:2},{x:1}]  but I get 3

Comment: Array#push returns the new length of the array, which you assign to `x`. Try `console.log(myArray)`

Comment: you need to `console.log(myArray)` to get what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `push` is the length of the modified array. It isn't another reference to the same array, nor is it a new array.

If you want to log the array, then `console.log(myArray)` instead of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, push just returns the length of the new array and the array was modified in place.  Try:

`console.log(myArray)`

Answer (score 1):

myArray.push(myObj) returns a number of objects it has. you are displaying the array length. If we print myArray you could see the array of Object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should console.log(myArray); The way you do returns the new length of the array, which you assign another reference

**DEMO**

```js
let myArray = [{x:1},{x:2}];
let myObj = {x:1};
console.log(myArray);
myArray.push(myObj);

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.push() function is working properly, and it returns the new length of the array

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=a